# OGC : How to know which ogc service type is in my url location?

Tags: ogc

Having a predefined url for my ogc service how can i know if is wms or wfs: `/My/predefined/URL/`

Well i know that if i made `/My/predefined/URL/?request=GetCapabilities` i will find which service type is, but is there any faster way something like `GetServiceType`?

I want categorize my url from wms and wfs, and in some cases i could find that information directly on url but in other cases not. How can i do that without have to ask for each url getCapabilites and lookup for servicetype attribut to see if is wms or wfs.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `GetCapabilities` request is for. In some cases the URL may contain a hint which service type it is, but that's not always the case. So you have to ask the server and this is what `GetCapabilities` is for.

Comment: well, it would be nice to have a faster request, since the GetCapabilities is too much information to answer a simple question.

Comment: @ePascoal There is no standard `GetServiceType` request. *"too much information to answer a simple question"* - you can't expect standard interfaces to have an "simple" operation for every possible "simple question". From my point of view asking for services type is strange - why did not you keep this information when gathering URLs in the first place?

Comment: I know that is a standard and doesnt exist. In fact is not a simple question but is the first of all. "which service is this?" and yes i understand it cannot be implemented once that we are talking about a standarization of webservices. In my case i dont control the URLs that is sent to my web application. I have several urls and i must request getcapabilites to know if is a wms or wfs.

Comment: So you have your answer then.

Answer (score 1):

> Well i know that if i made /My/predefined/URL/?request=GetCapabilities
>   i will find which service type is, but is there any faster way
>   something like GetServiceType?

Actually it is invalid to ask for a GetCapabilities response for an unknown service type, so if you can do this then your service must have the service parameter preset somehow.

To find out if your service is a WMS you need:

```
/My/predefined/URL/?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&
```

To find out if your service is a WFS you need:

```
/My/predefined/URL/?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&
```

To find out if your service is a WCS you need:

```
/My/predefined/URL/?request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS&
```

same for SOS, CSW, WPS, WMTS...

If the service is of the type specified you will get a GetCapabilities response, otherwise you will get an exception like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
  <ServiceException code="InvalidParameterValue" locator="request">msWCSDispatch(): WCS server error. WCS request not enabled. Check wcs/ows_enable_request settings.
  </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Note it is entirely possible for a service endpoint like `/My/predefined/URL/?` to have multiple service types available.